# How Home HVAC controller send commands for Cooling, Heating?

Tags: controller

i want to know how the Hvac controller sends commands to the hvac for cooling and heating.
i mean when we push on + or - button for example to adjust the temperature, what happens on the other side? is it simple contact which activate the cooling for certain time ?
I did not find any schematics google.
Can anyone explain how it works.

My project is to replace the HVAC controller with a Raspberry pi card.
i saw in some documentation:
W = heater control line
Y = Cooler compressor
RH = Heat/Cooler power
G = Fan control
C = Option

for example i want to adjust a cooling, when i push the button -, am i send a signal like close contact between 0V and Y ?

Thank you

Comment: Yes, they are simple contact outputs.  Look up the connection diagram for any old Heat/Cool thermostat for the basics.  Heat pumps usually have additional contacts for at least the reversing valve.  The thermostat also usually controls the blower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Home thermostats interface with the rest of the HVAC system with a few wires. Usually they switch low voltage (eg. 24VAC) with several contacts or solid-state switches, to control **heat**, **cool** and **fan** operation.

If you have an electronic one, the buttons or whatever go to a micro in the thermostat, not outside of the thermostat.

The wire color codes and names are fairly standardized, look at Honeywell, Nest etc. wiring diagrams.

Note that the other side of the 24VAC is typically not present in the thermostat housing.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, so it seems very simple to send signal to the hvac, i just have to set GPIOs of RPI card for Heat, Cool and one temperature sensor to measure the actual temp and then a C or Python code to adjust set points.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Of course you need to control relays etc. with the GPIO outputs to switch the 24VAC. You may wish to incorporate a fail-safe provision in case the RPi fails to control properly. For example, in Canada we'd want to prevent the house from getting too cold, in order to protect pets and pipes from freezing.

Comment: Thank you very much Sphero, i start to simulate with RPI, thanks a lot